# Implementation of Handsontable with angular 9 and node 16

Tags: node.js, angular, handsontable

I am using angular 9 for frontend and node js 16 for backend. So which version of Handsontable free version I can use with that env set up

Comment: The last free (MIT) version of Handsontable is 6.2.3 or you can check the oldest wrapper version https://www.npmjs.com/package/@handsontable/angular

Comment: I just rechecked - it's 6.2.2, not 6.2.3